# In Python, how to set value for one __init__ variable based on another?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, scope, initialization

```
def __init__(self):
    #self.data = []
    self.random_word = random.choice(open("EnglishDictionary.txt").readlines()).strip()
    self.length_notice = "The word you're guessing is {} letters long.".format(len(random_word))
```

This just returns the error: Name 'random_word' is undefined

Comment: You can have __init__ call a function, and pass in that random_word that you generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set `self.random_word`, not `random_word`, so you need to *use* `self.random_word`:

```
self.length_notice = "The word you're guessing is {} letters long.".format(len(self.random_word))
                                                                   # Add self. ^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use it:

```
def __init__(self):
    #self.data = []
    with open("EnglishDictionary.txt") as f:
        msg = "The word you're guessing is {} letters long."
        self.random_word = random.choice(f).strip()
        self.length_notice = msg.format(len(self.random_word))
```

Ask yourself, though, if `self.random_word` really needs to be an instance attribute, or if `random_word` can simply be a local variable inside the function, like `msg`.